# Barplot with frequency by specific factor

Tags: expression, spotfire, tibco

I would like to create a barplot in TIBCO Spotfire with frequency on Y axis based on two factors: Stage and Genotype.

This is the standard expression that I have from Spotfire:

```
Count() THEN [Value] / Sum([Value]) OVER (All([Axis.X]))
```

It turns out, I do not want the frequency over ALL the data, but within Stage. In a way that the sum of the frequency within each is stage it will be 100%.

I watched some videos and I still did not figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to find a solution to your problem but could't find a working expression. This can still help you :

What I would have done in your case is :

- remove the Genotype from the X Axis
- set the visualization as a 100% stacked bars (with right click)
- add the Genotype as a color by parameter (in the visualization options)